# Postgres tuning a query with RECURSIVE CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I use PostgreSQL 13.5.
There is recursive cte query:

```
-- query1
with recursive cte AS
(
   SELECT * FROM ad_definition def WHERE def.ad_definition_id = 'BASIC'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT def.* FROM ad_definition def JOIN cte c ON c.ad_definition_id = def.ad_definition_parent_id
) SELECT * FROM cte
```

it returns 2 rows ('BASIC', 'EXTENDED')

when I use the result in the next query execution is fast

```
-- query2
explain 
SELECT * FROM ad_definition d
join ad on ad.ad_definition_id = d.ad_definition_id
WHERE d.ad_definition_name in ('BASIC', 'EXTENDED')
```

execution plan shows the Index Scan is used:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..225244.60 rows=1757853 width=241)
  ->  Seq Scan on ad_definition d  (cost=0.00..2.15 rows=2 width=76)
        Filter: ((ad_definition_name)::text = ANY ('{BASIC,EXTENDED}'::text[]))
  ->  Index Scan using i_ad_ad_definition_id on ad  (cost=0.43..91526.98 rows=2109424 width=165)
        Index Cond: (ad_definition_id = d.ad_definition_id)
```

but when I join both queries into one

```
-- query3
explain with recursive cte AS (
   SELECT * FROM ad_definition def WHERE def.ad_definition_id = 1000
   UNION ALL
   SELECT def.* FROM ad_definition def JOIN cte c ON c.ad_definition_id = def.ad_definition_parent_id
) SELECT * FROM cte 
join ad on ad.ad_definition_id = cte.ad_definition_id
```

results are equal. but the execution is much slower and I see in the execution plan a Seq Scan is used :-(

```
Hash Join  (cost=30.23..500069.30 rows=10547119 width=731)
  Hash Cond: (ad.ad_definition_id = cte.ad_definition_id)
  CTE cte
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..28.57 rows=51 width=76)
        ...
  ->  Seq Scan on ad  (cost=0.00..355016.19 rows=10547119 width=165)
  ->  Hash  (cost=1.02..1.02 rows=51 width=566)
        ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=51 width=566)
```

Is it possible to use the CTE and force the index scan at the same time?

Comment: The execution plans generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)` would be more helpful

Comment: It didn't help. doesn't matter `with recursive cte AS  materialized (`  or 
`with recursive cte AS not materialized (` execution plan use Seq Scan

Answer (score 0):

Materialized or not materialized does not affect the use of these indexes. Materialized - just executes the request once, even if it is called multiple times. In your query, the CTE acts as a kind of subquery. You have written a join on table `ad` after CTE. That is, firstly running query inside the CTE. After then result CTE inserted into a temp table and after then the join is running, so you get `seq scan`. Probably also the result of CTE is big data. You would be better off putting the `join ad on ad.ad_definition_id = cte.ad_definition_id` part inside the CTE. If you do it, I think that `index scan` will be work.